# Cannot get number to increase with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code and no matter what I cannot get the number to increase:

```
  $(".next").click(function (e) {
console.log(e)
    var number = 0;
    $(".numvalue").text(number++);
  });
```

I can see the event getting logged in the console each time I click but the number does not increase. Why would this be the case?

I am using Linux Mint 20.3 and Firefox 101.0.1

Comment: declare var  outside of the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the variable declaration outside the method, like this

```
var number = 0;     
$(".next").click(function (e) {
 console.log(e)
 $(".numvalue").text(number++);
});
```

[Here are the javascript basics](https://www.flyingegret.com/title030_javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is to declare `number` *outside* of the function. Declaring it inside means that it gets reset to `0` every time the event happens:

```
var number = 0;

$(".next").click(function (e) {
  $(".numvalue").text(number++);
});
```

The better solution would be to avoid the need for the global variable at all. You can do this by providing a function to `text()` which accepts the current value as an argument and returns the new value based on that:

```js
$(".next").click(() => $(".numvalue").text((i, t) => (+t || 0) + 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<span class="numvalue">0</span>
```